# BsonWriter 'create' doesn't exist anymore in 2.2.3.3 version, what changed?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I just updated my MongoDB.Bson assembly from 1.10.1.73 to 2.2.3.3.

And BsonWriter.Create doesn't exist anymore. It will be REALLY nice if the old documentation from api.mongodb.org has a link to a page to explain what to do with their changes, but they don't have it......

So anyone has any idea what to do about it?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you will need to use an implementaion of IBsonWriter.
JsonWriter is provided in MongoDB.Bson.IO.

```
       var document = documents.FirstOrDefault<BsonDocument>();

        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var jw = new JsonWriter(sw);
        if (document != null)
            BsonSerializer.Serialize(jw, document);
```